# IntelliJ IDEA change default breakpoint suspend policy

Tags: multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm migrating from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1.

In Eclipse, when adding a new breakpoint default suspend policy is to stop for current thread.
In IntelliJ it is suspend all threads.

Does IntelliJ have a configuration to change that default suspension policy for (at least) new breakpoints?

I've seen the option **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Debugger** > **Stepping**, **Resume only the current thread**, that I assume that when hiting resume button will only continue current stopped thread, but if breakpoint was for **All**, what will happen to the others?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Please follow the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95103

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can easily change the default behaviour for all new created breakpoints.

Just create a breakpoint, right click on the breakpoint and change the Suspend policy to Thread. Then a button "Make default" appears on the right and you just need to select it.

Comment: how about making it default for all projects?